# How to get Mediatek MT7601u working on 10.13.6?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, high-sierra, usb

My 2011 MacBook pro has a broken WiFi card so I have been using USB dongles instead. My previous one stopped working so I have been trying to get a Mediatek MT 7601u working. This MacBook Pro is triple boot and this dongle works fine in Windows 10 but I get nothing in Mac OS and Ubuntu. When I tried to download drivers on the website, the mac link downloaded the linux drivers which don't work even on linux! When I searched this up, all the links pointed at Hackintosh installs. Has anyone got this type of USB dongle working on a real Mac running 10.13.6?